# Monopoly: pricing.

Tags: calculus

The total costs of a monopolistic firm are CT = 10q + 2 * (q ^ 2).

Assuming that the firm decides to produce q* = 10 and that for that level of production the price elasticity of demand is equal to:
| epsilon q, p | = 3,
determine the price charged by the company.

My partial solution:
Marginal cost = 10 + 4q
Having q=10 => Marginal cost = 50

The reference solution is: price = 75.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you for considering my request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general pricing rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerner_index) is that
$$
\dfrac{p-c'}{p} = \dfrac{1}{|\varepsilon|}
$$
or
$$
\dfrac{p-50}{p}=\dfrac{1}{3}
$$
so that
$$
3p^* = 150 + p^*
$$
or
$$
p^* = 75.
$$

Comment: You are so kind, thank you for having helped me! ;-)